# Labels next to points in a plot using ggplotly() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I was wondering if there is a way to put labels next to points in a `ggplotly()` plot. If I use `geom_text` or `geom_text_repel` in `ggplot()`, the result is ok. But then if I call `ggplotly()`, I cannot see the labels I created anymore.

For example:

```
require(ggplot)
require(plotly)
x <- c("01/01/2007","04/03/2008","28/11/2008","13/06/2009")
y <- c(25, 50, 75, 100)
x <- as.Date(x, "%d/%m/%Y")
labels <- c("observer1", "observer2", "observer3", "observer4")
x_lab <- "date"
y_lab <- "score"
mydata <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(col="blue")
ggplotly()
```

I want "labels" to appear next to points but I was not able to find a way to do it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that you know that this error doesn't happen in `ggplot2`, It happens in `plotly` because the functions of `plotly` are so much different than the `ggplot2`. Not all the functions from `ggplot2` package can be passed to `plotly`.
But if you are still obsessed with `plotly` due to its additional features, I highly recommend you to use the `plot_ly()` function to create plots instead of `ggplot()`.

I've provided a head start for you down below:

```
require(ggplot)
require(plotly)
x <- c("01/01/2007","04/03/2008","28/11/2008","13/06/2009")
y <- c(25, 50, 75, 100)
x <- as.Date(x, "%d/%m/%Y")
labels <- c("observer1", "observer2", "observer3", "observer4")
x_lab <- "date"
y_lab <- "score"
mydata <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
plot_ly(mydata, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
             marker = list(size = 10)) %>%
  add_annotations(x = mydata$x,
                  y = mydata$y,
                  text = labels)
```

The output of this graph is in this link 
[Graph Output from plot_ly function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0eXZ.png)

Comment: Consider upvoting if this helped.
@Sergio Nolazco. Consider accepting this answer if it fixed your problem

Comment: Thanks @Vedha Viyash. plot_ly() function seems to work much better but how add_annotations actually work? In this specific example it works but my original data is a dataframe and labels are one column in that dataframe. When I follow your code it seems that it does not link each label to its corresponding x and y values in the dataframe. Arrows and labels appear everywhere over the plot, not only next to data points.

Comment: I actually prefer ggplot2, because its easy to use and very flexible with regards to application in r. If I want to "zoom in", "download", "explore in depth".... I use Shiny to create a small app and so that which is more flexible than using plotly. I used to prefer plotly before, weeks after I started using ggplot2. But to use the full Potential of plotly you have to learn so much similat to learning Shiny. So I decided to learn Shiny instead.
The links for Learning Shiny:http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/
Text Annotations in plotly : https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/

Comment: so it is possible to do something similar in ggplot? Labels that just appear when putting the cursor over the point, like not just coordinates but also another variable info such as "labels" variable in this example, all info from the dataframe.

Comment: Of course you can do that there, you can do more than that...You can specify what happens when you single click, double click and hover. You can link one graph to another. I highly recommend you to go through this video to understand the full potential of Shiny and ggplot together. If you don't have 1 hour left to spare just skip through the video and watch (30:00 - 31:30), (34:40 - 35:40) and (46:00 - 48:00) Heres the link : https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/interactive-graphics-with-shiny/

Comment: Anytime @Sergio Nolazco